# Spacy Python how to count numbers with /

Tags: python, spacy

I am using Spacy for text analysis. I need to count the number of occurrences of numbers in this text where the text contains the expression '1/2'.

How to calculate the numbers "1" and "2" separately without resorting to operations with regular expressions?

**My code:**

```
for token in doc:
    if token.pos_ =='NUM':
        m.append(token.text)
    
    for item in set(m):
        print(f'"{item}" was found {m.count(item)} times in text')
```

Comment: Count or calculate?

Comment: Could you give some examples of the string `doc` and what you would like the result to be?

Comment: "we need 2 glass of water and 3/2 a spoon of milk"  - output should be like "3" 1 time, "2" - 2 times

Comment: I think spacy has tools for processing such data, but I can't find and use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of your question, you want to count the number of occurrences of numbers in a text where the expression `'1/2'` pops up. In that case, the following will work:

```
test_str = "I like 1/2 to code 1/2 a lot"
search_str = "1/2"
print(f"Number of occurrences: {test_str.count(search_str)}")

calc = eval("1/2") # evaluates the expression as pythonic code
print(f"The expression '1/2', calculated to float: {calc}")

# >>> Number of occurrences: 2
# >>> The expression '1/2', calculated to float: 0.5
```

I also added a way to 'calculate' the expression. You can use the `eval` function, which will evaluate the string as pythonic code. Hopefully this helps!

EDIT: To count the total number of expressions, you can do something like this:

```
test_str = "I 1 would 1 like 1/2 to code 1/2 a lot"
search_str = "1/2"
digit_list = search_str.split('/') # creates list ['1', '2']

print(f"Number of occurrences of {search_str}: {test_str.count(search_str)}")
for digit in digit_list:
    print(f"Number of occurrences of digit {digit}: {test_str.count(digit)}")

# >>> Number of occurrences of 1/2: 2
# >>> Number of occurrences of digit 1: 4
# >>> Number of occurrences of digit 2: 2
```

Comment: sorry, but I'm trying to count the numbers "1" and "2" in the expression "1/2" separately. For example, for the expression "you need 2 glasses of water and 3/2 spoons of milk" - the output should be like "3" 1 time, " 2" - 2 times

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I posted an edit to my answer which also counts the individual digits. It uses `"1/2".split("/")` to get a list of all the digits which are in the expression `"1/2"`. You can also generalize this to count the occurrences of all digits 0-9, depending on your use case :)